# Модератор рассмотрел вашу тревогу, но

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, тревоги

Сейчас сообщение об отклонении выглядит вот так:

> модератор рассмотрел вашу тревогу, но не нашёл причин для каких-либо действий

причём, оно же показывается и для давно отклонённых тревог.

Но вроде бы сообщение раньше было другим. У старого варианта не было такого акцента на отсутствие необходимости в каких-либо действиях. Мне кажется, он тут лишний. Или это такая попытка более чётко отделить эту причину от других?

> тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, немного отличается.

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Это про то, что автор тревоги посчитал контент нарушающим правила, а модератор не увидел нарушений. К примеру, тревогнул как оскорбительное, но модератор решил, что не оскорбительно. Т.е, тревоги верная, но модератор решил, что нарушений нет.

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

А здесь посыл вроде как в том, что "не надо использовать тревоги не по назначению". К примеру, не нужно использовать тревоги, если вопрос плох - нужно голосовать за закрытие. Т.е, такие тревог вообще не по делу.

Но тут есть нюанс. Насколько я помню, люди с недостаточной репутацией не могу голосовать за закрытие, они могут тревогать. И эти тревоги к нам попадают.

Comment: Ну у меня рука не поднимается поставить _"но не нашёл причин для каких-либо действий",_ если я потом отредактировал что-то.

Comment: А какой прошлый перевод был? Или это я так внезапно его переосмыслил просто?

Comment: @Qwertiy на моей памяти перевод всегда таким был.

Comment: А может всё-таки "для её удовлетворения" было?